# Windows Mapped Drive of DNS A Record Seems Cached

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an A record setup for a specific host IP. I'm then using the A record as the part of the UNC path for a network drive mapping (X:).

```
net use x: \\my-arecord.host.com\share
```

My problem is when I attempt to reassign the IP in the A record. The Windows 2012 servers mapping X: seem to be caching the IP address and not refetching the DNS resolution.

How can I force remapping of drive to honor DNS TTL and resolved IP?

Comment: Four things: 1. Lower the TTL of the DNS record. 2. Unmap the network drive. 3. Flush the client DNS cache. 4. Remap the network drive. - Simply changing the DNS record isn't going to cause the client to disconnect from the network drive or to unmap it

Comment: @joeqwerty that is the problem, TTL is 300 seconds, even unmapping and remapping still results in the old IP.

Comment: It sounds like the old name is still in the client DNS cache. Have you looked at the client DNS cache when this problem occurs?

Comment: @joeqwerty how is client DNS cache reviewed?

Comment: From a command prompt run "ipconfig /displaydns"... without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To force your client to reload caches DNS records do the following:

From an elevated command prompt run: `ipconfig /flushdns`

You may also need to Reload the DNS zone in Active directory:

1. Launch DNS Manager
2. Connect to your DNS server if not already connected
3. Expand the server and Forward Lookup Zones
4. Right click on your zone and select Reload

If you're querying a record that is being hosted by a different DNZ server than the one you're querying then you will have to clear the cached record on that DNS server if you want to force it to refresh faster.

1. Launch DNS Manager
2. Click View -> Advanced
3. Connect to your DNS server if not already connected
4. Expand the server and Cached Lookups
5. Expand .(root) and navigate down to your TLD and subsequent domain and record.  You can delete this cached record which will force your DNS server to query the record from your domain's name server.

Comment: Tried the ```ipconfig /flushdns`` didn't work. Any manual GUI navigation leads to tech debt where we want to automate.

Comment: You can still try the solution to see if it fixes the problem and then work on a way to automate if necessary.  Technical debt/automation were not mentioned as a constraint in your original question.